# How to display (the hours of) a local time in a spinner in JavaFx

Tags: javafx, spinner, localtime

How do I set the value of `SpinnerValueFactory<LocalTime> valueFactory = new SpinnerValueFactory<LocalTime>()` in a spinner?

Attempting to set and display the value in the spinner editor with `hrsSpinner.getValueFactory().setValue(valueFactory);` , Java tells me:

```
The method setValue(LocalTime) in the type SpinnerValueFactory<LocalTime> is not applicable for the arguments (SpinnerValueFactory<LocalTime>).
```

Another approach I've tried is `hrsSpinner.setValueFactory(valueFactory);`. I get no errors. But the hours are initially not displayed in the spinner editor until I've clicked on the spinner to increment or decrement the hours.

Any ideas how I can solve my problem? Here is a sample of my code I'm using

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
int hour;
this.hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

if(hourRadioButton.isSelected() == true) 
        {
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh");    

            ObservableList<String> hours = FXCollections.observableArrayList(String.valueOf(hour));
            SpinnerValueFactory<LocalTime> valueFactory = new SpinnerValueFactory<LocalTime>() {

                {
                    setConverter(new LocalTimeStringConverter(formatter,null));
                }

                @Override
                public void decrement(int steps) {
                    if(getValue() == null)
                    {
                        setValue(LocalTime.now());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LocalTime localTime = (LocalTime) getValue();
                        setValue(localTime.minusHours(1));
                    }                   
                }

                @Override
                public void increment(int steps) {
                    if (this.getValue() == null)
                    {
                        setValue(LocalTime.now());
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        LocalTime localTime = (LocalTime) getValue();
                        setValue(localTime.plusHours(1));
                    }               
                }               
            };

            //hrsSpinner.setValueFactory(valueFactory);
            hrsSpinner.getValueFactory().setValue(valueFactory);
        }
```

Thank you very much in advance for your time and help!!!
AvJoe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hrsSpinner.getValueFactory()` is an expression of type `SpinnerValueFactory<LocalTime>`. Using `setValue` on this is not possible with this parameter and it wouldn't do what you want.

Use the setter for the `valueFactory` property instead:

```
hrsSpinner.setValueFactory(valueFactory);
```

This way of setting the value factory seems to stem from the bad practice of using the setter of the property object instead of using the more concise and thus easier to parse version using the setter corresponding to the property. The version using the property object's setter would be

```
hrsSpinner.valueFactoryProperty().set(valueFactory);
```

in this case.

Furthermore I don't recommend mixing `Calendar` and `java.time` API. If you've got the choice, go with the `java.time` api completely. It provides the same functionality and is much easier to use imho. E.g. assuming you wanted to use the calendar to truncate the value to full hours, you could use `truncateTo` instead:

```
SpinnerValueFactory<LocalTime> factory = new SpinnerValueFactory<LocalTime>() {

    {
        setValue(defaultValue());
    }

    private LocalTime defaultValue() {
        return LocalTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS);
    }

    @Override
    public void decrement(int steps) {
        LocalTime value = getValue();
        setValue(value == null ? defaultValue() : value.minusHours(steps));
    }

    @Override
    public void increment(int steps) {
        LocalTime value = getValue();
        setValue(value == null ? defaultValue() : value.plusHours(steps));
    }


};
Spinner<LocalTime> spinner = new Spinner<>();
spinner.setValueFactory(factory);
```

Comment: It works. Thank you for your help and advice! The hour is displayed in the format `HH:00`. Is there a way to display it in the format `HH`?

Comment: Use the `setConverter` part from your code... You probably should pass the fromatter to both constructor parameters tough...